# Does java 1.4 support SOAP Binding 1.2?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java1.4

I have a requirement where i have to develop a Web service Client to consume a web service.

The WSDL shows that the SOAP Binding is 1.2
but the JDK version in Development and JRE in App server is 1.4.

I tried to develop the Web service Proxy through JDeveloper 10.1.2 but it failed the generation saying that the WSDL is invalid.

Is Soap Binding 1.2 supported by java 1.4???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is not part of Java SE.

Some SOAP support is included Java EE ... via the `javax.wsl.soap`, but it looks like you would be better of using the JAX-WS support in [Metro 1.4](http://metro.java.net/1.4/docs/soap12.html).

Unfortunately for you, Metro 1.4 requires Java 1.5 (u2) or later.

However, you should be seriously considering a platform upgrade anyway.  Java 1.4 was end-of-lifed a long time ago. Unless you are paying for Oracle support, you won't have access to security patches ... and there have been some significant ones recently.

Comment: I understand your point but its an old product on which i am working and i cant upgrade the same overnight.